# Selenium - Unable to mouse over with Firefox

Tags: selenium, firefox, geckodriver

Has anyone found a workaround for mouse hover over an element in Firefox, given the following issue?

```
org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: mouseMoveTo
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
```

The command works on Edge, IE, Chrome.

I'm using the latest geckodriver (0.18.0) and Firefox (54.0.1)

Comment: Are you using `Actions` class for that ? Then it won't work in FF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see there is a bug opened for this. 
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4008

However, as a work around you could try to change geckodriver or Firefox version. if this is not possible you could always use javascript to scroll to element.

```
je.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",element);
```

However this will only put the Element into View Port. It won't put mouse over and element. So it won't generate any Mouseoever event if you are interested in.

The reason for this is very simple, The mouse movement is controlled by your OS and not JavaScript. It's by design for security.

Comment: Thanks Gaurang for your help. In my instance, this didn't reveal the element, normally revealled with a mouseover, but perhaps it may work for others

Comment: could you try this `je.executeScript("arguments[0].foucs();",element);` after above script.

Comment: Thanks Gaurang, much appreciated :)